# JSF 2 doesn't find my method

Tags: jsf-2, view, controller

So I have a view that create pie chart. Th recurring code looks like this.

```
function drawChart() {
            var dataBest = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                dataBest.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                dataBest.addColumn('number', 'Number');
                dataBest.addRows([
                <ui:repeat  value="#{dashboardController.bestSelling()}" var="sale">
                    [ '#{sale[0].prodId.prodName}', #{sale[1]}],
                </ui:repeat >
                ]);
                var options = {'title':'Best Sold Products', 'width':400,'height':300};
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('test'));
                chart.draw(dataBest, options);
       }
```

And in my controller called DashboardController I have:

```
public String bestSelling() {
        List<Sales> bestSelling = saleService.getBestSellingProduct(country,gender,status,income);
        return new Gson().toJson(bestSelling);
    }
```

But, when I go on my page, I have the following error:
/faces/all.xhtml @22,83 value="#{dashboardController.bestSelling}": The class 'com.***.***.managedbean.DashboardController' does not have the property 'bestSelling'.

I don't understand what I did wrong there.

Comment: Huh? Why are you trying to iterate over a `String`?

Comment: Well, I've been told I needed to pass my list in json to be able to use it, so I just iterate over all the elements of my json. But for now, I can't even get my string to come so …

Comment: You're not returning a Java `List`. You're returning a Java `String` (representing an array in JSON format). You're supposed to just print it plain vanilla (and never perform business logic in getter methods).

Comment: Yeah, I know, my first method getBestSellingProduct return a list. I transform this list into a String. If there is a better method, I'll take it ! :D

Comment: To be honest, i don't like to have to convert my list into a string. My list return actually an object and a int (hence this line [ '#{sale[0].prodId.prodName}', #{sale[1]}] ). If there is a way to use my List inside the view, it'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

You're not running the code you think you're running. Look at the error message:

> /faces/all.xhtml @22,83 value="#{dashboardController.bestSelling}

It mentions the method without the parentheses. So, you've apparently added it later in, but the webapp project is not properly been saved/cleaned/rebuilt/redeployed/restarted.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there's many more wrong with this approach (attempting to use `<ui:repeat>` to iterate over a Java `String` as #1 thinking mistake), but you'll experience this as soon as you fix the current problem. Hint: JSF is a HTML code generator and JS is part of that HTML.

Comment: I tried to clean/build my project and re-run it but it didn't change a thing.